# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in .NET

Tags: .net, excel, exception

I got this error when running an application that involves Microsoft Office's Excel. My computer doesn't have a Microsoft Office installed so I think that might be the problem. I referenced some libraries that would help the application run but it didn't help and I still encounter the error.

This is the whole error message:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in 'application name'.

Additional information: COM object with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is either not valid or not registered."

Below are the libraries I used:

- Interop.Excel
- Interop.KEYCODEV2Lib
- Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core
- Interop.Office
- Interop.VBIDE
- Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
- Microsoft.Vbe.Interop
- stdole
- System
- System.Data
- System.Drawing
- System.Windows.Form
- System.XML

Here is the code block where the error occurs:

```
cboCounty.Enabled = False
    If ofdExcel.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        txtFile3.Text = ofdExcel.FileName
        btnClear.Enabled = True
        Application.DoEvents()

        myExcel = New Excel.Application
        myExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

        wbLog = myExcel.Workbooks.Open(ofdExcel.FileName, True, True)
        cboCounty.Items.Clear()

        For s As Integer = 1 To wbLog.Worksheets.Count
            wsLog = wbLog.Worksheets(s)
            If UCase(wsLog.Name) <> "SUMMARY" Then
                cboCounty.Items.Add(wsLog.Name)
            End If
        Next

        cboCounty.Enabled = True
    End If
```

On the line `myExcel = New Excel.Application` where the error occurs.

Could somebody help me with a work around with this.
Thank You.

Comment: The exception is trying to tell you that Office is not installed.  Required.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this is that your opening Excel externally as an unhandled object, if you do not have it installed this is your problem.

When using external objects remember to run garbage collection with them as they are on the unmanaged heap and cannot be cleaned automatically from within the .NET framework.